# $_POST vars combined with MySQL gives MySQL syntax error - near '1' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

The query works but the error report "bugs" me :)

```
//the vars i use
$pos = $_POST['positie'];   //this can be B1 till M100
$kolom = $pos[0];           //get first char of the $pos string 
$rij = substr($pos, 1, 3);  //get the rest of the chars

$sql= mysql_query("UPDATE floorplan SET available='0' WHERE kolom='$kolom' AND rij='$rij'") or die( mysql_error() );
```

the kolom is varchar(4), rij is int(4) and avaiable is a BOOLEAN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Dude. **Check your input!!**

Comment: First of all it's not safe to run mysql queries like that - you can face sql injection. To debug your case add echo "UPDATE floorplan SET available='0' WHERE kolom='$kolom' AND rij='$rij'" statement to see what actually happens, probably there's no post variables you are relying on.

Comment: is your post variable an array?

Comment: its just to test, but still why am i getting this error?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com B or C or D or .. till M

Comment: @NikosTsirakis its like i stated in the comment "B1" or "C59" or it could even be "K100"

Comment: This is what I'd do, to help debugging:

`$sql = "UPDATE floorplan SET available='0' WHERE kolom='$kolom' AND rij='$rij'";

print($sql);`

Then you can see exactly what's being queried.

Comment: `near '' at line 1` indicates, that the error must be at the end, because no chars are left in the SQL-String. Check your `$rij`-value

Comment: @EM-Creations this is what i have between those vars and the query  `echo "original string = ".$pos."<br />";
    echo "kolom = ". $kol ." and rij = ". $rij."<br />";`

Comment: @TrustMe That's not good enough, make it output EXACTLY what you're sending to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql, boolean is simply synonym for TINYINT(1). A value of 0 is considered FALSE. So, change

```
$rij = substr($pos, 1, 3);
```

to

```
$rij = intval(substr($pos, 1, 3));
```

and query to

```
"UPDATE floorplan SET available=0 WHERE kolom='$kolom' AND rij=$rij"
```

would solve your problem but like others said, you should think about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: rij is not boolean! available is

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed take care of my error. I will offcourse try to prevent SQL injection :)

Comment: @KiroConeski you are right. What i used was the 0 withouth qoutes and i left my substr like it was in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $pos has a value of "B1".

Then, `substr($pos, 1, 3);` will return an out of bounds exception.

Try with `substr($pos, 1);`

Comment: Thanks, Kiro i think this was part of the solution :)